# Dual citizenship (US and Ecuador) travel to China

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china, borders, dual-nationality, ecuadorian-citizens

I have valid US and Ecuadorian passports due to birth in Ecuador and being naturalized in the US. I plan on traveling to Shenzhen via Hong Kong. Basically my flights are to/from Hong Kong and I will take a train to the Futian Border Crossing (福田口岸) and cross to/from Shenzhen.

Is it OK to apply for a Chinese L-Visa on my Ecuadorian passport instead of my US passport?

When traveling to HK/Mainland China, is the following sequence OK?:

**Show US passport**

At JFK Cathay Airlines check-in:

At US Immigration Control

At HK border control on arrival from US

At HK exit border control in Futian BC

**Show Ecuadorian passport with Chinese L-visa**

At Chinese entrance border control in Futian BC

At Chinese exit border control in Futian BC

**Show US passport**

At HK entrance border control in Futian BC

At HKG airport check-in, border control

At entrance to the US

I don't know much about the metro border control and if it works like airport border control - all I know is it exists.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China) that citizens of Ecuador are entitled to 30-day visa-free entry into China.  If that fits your travel plans, you might not need any visa at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unless you are staying for more than 30 days, you do not need to a visa to enter mainland China.](http://ec.china-embassy.org/chn/xwdt/t1388151.htm)

You will need to show your Ecuadorian passport at check-in. When landing in HK you can show them either passport. When exiting Hong Kong, you show them the Ecuadorian one again. So the only time you will actually need the US passport is to re-enter the US, so you will have to show it when flying out of Hong Kong.

Comment: When exiting HK, he needs to show **the same** passport he showed when entering HK. And he also needs to show the US passport (or both) to the airline when leaving US.

Comment: Really? I think he can show the Ecuadorian passports. How else would a foreigner leave for example? But, yes, enter and exit in HK should use whichever same passport.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your sequence looks ok. Note that there is no US immigration control on your way out of US, so your second step will be missing.

Also you might need to show **both** passports at HK exit and Mainland China exit - HK side might want to ensure you'd get into China, and vice versa.

Note, however, that China issues US citizens a 10 year visitor visa (same cost as 1yr visa); not sure if it is the same for Ecuadorean citizens. Thus if you plan to visit China again in near future, you might consider the cost calculation.

Regarding crossing, it is similar to airport - you do NOT cross the border in a train, and the immigration formalities are not conducted in a train. You leave a train, walk through HK immigration, walk to Mainland China (I believe you walk over a bridge on this crossing), come to Mainland, fill up your forms, go through immigration, and jump into subway.

Comment: Hong Kong immigration is extremely unlikely to ask about entry to mainland China since it is not part of the flight itinerary. Unless the asker volunteers the information, they will not know about the planed train segment. Also, Ecuadorian citizens need to no visa unless staying longer than 30 days.

Comment: He is leaving HK through Futian, which is overland border crossing. The way it works, when you exit the HK side, there is no other place to go but to the mainland side. And they do occasionally check docs.